# Использование While вместе с функцией

Tags: php, алгоритм

обычно, в библиотеках встречаются подобные конструкции:

`while($res = make($arr)) {
     ...
}`

цикл выполняется до тех пор, пока тру, собственно, интересно как работает функция `make`? отправляют массив(к примеру)... приведите пожалуйста пример

Comment: Функция `make()` не является стандартной функцией языка. Ищите её код в библиотеке, про которую спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Самый частый пример это операция извлечения строки с данными из результата выборки из базы данных: [`mysqli_result::fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) или [`pg_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-fetch-array.php) или [`oci_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.oci-fetch-array.php). Все эти функции возвращают следующую строку из результата запроса в виде ассоциативного или нумерованного массива, в обратном случае возвращается `NULL` или `FALSE`. Конструкция цикла в вашем примере будет выполняться до тех пор, пока выражение в скобках не `FALSE` или `NULL`